# Placing order via REST API shows no product options in admin

Tags: magento-2.1

So I'm adding products with options into the cart with the REST API just fine. Order goes through the API fine as well but when I look at the order in the admin I see no product options in the summary of items in the order. I do, however, notice they are set to values by looking at the edit form of the order. It seems there's missing data for the order. How can I get options to show?

Here's an example of the json I send to add a product with options to the cart. I altered contents of a few fields for privacy.

```
{
    "cartItem": {
        "sku": "---",
        "name": "---",
        "qty": 1,
        "price": 85,
        "productType": "simple",
        "productOption": {
            "extensionAttributes": {
                "customOptions": [{
                    "option_id": 136,
                    "option_value": 707
                }]
            }
        },
        "extensionAttributes": {},
        "quote_id": "random string"
    }
}
```

Edit: Can anyone please help? I've upgrade from 2.1.3 to 2.1.5 and the issue still persists.

Comment: How did you add a product with options using REST API? Share information about parameters that you've used during call composition.